# Why do i got this : Array ( [name] => [pass] => )

Tags: php, session

Why do i get this when i print my session :
Array ( [name] => [pass] => ) ?

Below is my code

My main page for user to input, login.php:

```
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="imgcontainer">
            <img src="KBR2xN6.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            </div>

            <div class="container">
            <label><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="name" required>
            <br />

            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pass" required>

            <button type="submit">Login</button>
            <button type="reset" class="cancelbtn">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

To connect to local server, connections.php:

```
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "netbook 1 malaysia";

try {
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo 'Connection Failed : '.$ex->getMessage();
}
```

My session page, session.php:

```
session_start();
include('connections.php');

$username = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM pengguna WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
$result = $connect->query($sql);

if($result->rowcount()>0){
    foreach($result AS $data){
        $_SESSION['name'] = $data['name'];
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $data['pass'];

    echo "<script>alert('Login Success');
            window.location.href='view.php';
            </script>";
    }
}

else {
    echo "<script>alert('Login Failed');
            window.location.href='login.php';
            </script>"; 
}
```

Maybe my database failed ?

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Don't use JavaScript or Meta Tags to redirect a web page. Use [`Location: header`](//stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php) instead. Check [PHP the Right Way](//phptherightway.com/) for more up-to-date advice.

Comment: None of this code would output that content. Search your code for usage if `var_dump()`.

Comment: its ok as im still beginner, can u edit where is the wrong ?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). e. g. Use a better title.

Answer (score 0):

`$result` contains a resource, not database data directly.

When we expected just one row form database, no loop is needed. Using a loop you'll have just on name/pass in session, it'll be overwritten in your code for the last one.

```
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();
$_SESSION['name'] = $data['name'];
$_SESSION['pass'] = $data['pass'];

print_r($_SESSION);
```

Note that there is no reason to store password in session, the same as store password in database as a plaintext.

Answer (score -1):

Where you print session array? if you print session on view.php file then make sure to start session on view.php file.